# Slack API help needed

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api

The problem is creating a survey bot: 
Cannot figure out a way to render questions sequentially in Slack. We are using node to to write the API and testing in POSTMAN. When integrating to slack it grabs all questions together rather than one by one.

Currently the questions are being created using 'blocks'. It's one block we with three different sections in it. The slack docs doesn't have much about sending them one by one after one question is being answered.

````
blocks: [
                {
                  type: "section",
                  text: {
                    type: "plain_text",
                    text: `${title}`
                  }
                },
                {
                  type: "section",
                  block_id: "question1",
                  text: {
                    type: "plain_text",
                    text: `${question_1}`
                  }
                }, ```

What type of If conditional can we use to gain the sequential format rather than all as one?
````

Comment: I'm trying to understand and locate the javascript problem in this question.

Answer (score 0):

There are no conditions in messages. If you want to send questions one after the other you have to send them as individual messages. And implement the logic to wait for the next answer before sending them in your Slack app.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you happen to have an example?

Comment: Check out the tutorials on Slack for examples on working Slack apps. https://api.slack.com/tutorials